# Spectrum S3 Access Denied

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

NI am trying to load parquet data into Redshift via Redshift Spectrum.

I have my Trust relationship etc. setup and can assume the role fine from Redshift.

However I am getting an S3 Access Denied error which I cannot seem to solve.

S3 Bucket Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET>/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ArnEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalArn": [
                        "<ADMIN ROLE 1 ARN>",
                        "<ADMIN ROLE 2 ARN>"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketNotification",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET>/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ArnEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalArn": [
                        "arn:aws:iam::123456781234:role/GlueRole",
                        "arn:aws:iam::123456781234:role/ExtractSQLRole",
                        "arn:aws:iam::123456781234:role/RedshiftRole"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET>/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET>"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ArnNotEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalArn": [
                        "<ADMIN ROLE 1 ARN>",
                        "<ADMIN ROLE 2 ARN>",
                        "arn:aws:iam::123456781234:role/GlueRole",
                        "arn:aws:iam::123456781234:role/ExtractSQLRole",
                        "arn:aws:iam::123456781234:role/RedshiftRole"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Spectrum Schema Created with:

```
create external schema 'Schema1'
from data catalog
database 'spectrum_database'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::123456781234:role/RedshiftRole'
catalog_role 'arn:aws:iam::123456781234:role/GlueRole'
```

Glue Role:

```
  GlueRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: glue.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: redshift.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Condition:
              StringEquals:
                sts:ExternalId:
                  - arn:aws:iam::123456781234:role/GlueRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSGlueServiceRole
```

With this I get a list of tables but always this error:

[image]

I need to keep the bucket secured to only certain roles but also need Spectrum to query it... any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You have **explicit deny** for all your principles:

```
{
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET>/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET>"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ArnEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalArn": [
                        "<ADMIN ROLE 1 ARN>",
                        "<ADMIN ROLE 2 ARN>",
                        "arn:aws:iam::123456781234:role/GlueRole",
                        "arn:aws:iam::123456781234:role/ExtractSQLRole",
                        "arn:aws:iam::123456781234:role/RedshiftRole"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

The deny **always wins**, so you will be always denied, and no `allow` will change it. I'm not sure what do you want to achieve with this explict deny. Maybe you want to use `ArnNotEquals`?

Comment: Ah this is a typo as I have been playing around with the policy. It is set to ArnNotEquals. Fixed in the origional post. Thanks.